# gensim word2vec extremely big and what are the methods to make file size smaller?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have a pre-trained word2vec bin file by using skipgram. The file is pretty big (vector dimension of 200 ), over 2GB. I am thinking some methods to make the file size smaller. This bin file contains vectors for punctuation, some stop words. So, I want to know what are the options to decrease the file size for this word2vec. Is it safe to delete those punctuation and stop words rows and what would be the most effective way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a full `Word2Vec` model is chiefly determined by the chosen vector-size, and the size of the vocabulary.

So your main options for big savings is to train smaller vectors, or a smaller vocabulary.

Discarding a few hundred stop-words or punctuation-tokens won't make a noticeable dent in the model size.

Discarding many of the least-frequent words can make a big difference in model size – and often those less-frequent words aren't as important as you might think. (While there are a lot of them in total, each only appears rarely. And because they're rare in the training data, they often tend not to have very good vectors, anyway – based on few examples, and their training influence is swamped by the influence of more-frequent words.)

The easiest way to limit the vocabulary size is to use a higher `min_count` value during training (ignoring all words with fewer occurrences), or a  fixed `max_final_vocab` cap (which will keep only that many of the most-frequent words).

Note also that if you've been saving/reloading full `Word2Vec` models (via the gensim-internal `.save()`/`.load()` methods), you're retaining model internal weights that are only needed for continued training, and will nearly double the model-size on disk or re-load.

You may want to save just the raw word-vectors in the `.wv` property instead (via either the gensim-internal `.save()` or the `.save_word2vec_format()` methods).

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way would be to train using a smaller vocabulary, which is what [this repo](https://github.com/eyaler/word2vec-slim) does. "The final slim model has 299,567 words, saved in a 270 MB compressed word2vec format file, and loads in 20 seconds on my laptop."

Alternatively, you should consider using [fasttext](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html). Fasttext supports model quantization, which can significantly shrink the final model size - the example they give in their [blog post](https://fasttext.cc/blog/2017/10/02/blog-post.html#model-compression) on quantization demonstrates compressing a 350MB model to less than 1MB.

Answer (score 0):

I will complement the answer of @sam-h: fastText is a good choice if you want a small and accurate model for embeddings, because out-of-vocabulary words can be represented with their character n-grams, so you can avoid building a very large vocabulary.

However, the native fastText library supports compression only for supervised (classifier) models, so if you want a generic model for word embedding, this would not work. However, I have created a package [compress-fasttext](https://github.com/avidale/compress-fasttext) that can compress a 7GB model to 21MB with only small loss in the quality. [This post](https://towardsdatascience.com/compressing-unsupervised-fasttext-models-eb212e9919ca) describes the package in more details.